# IText won't read correctly PDF region

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` combined with a custom `ITextExtractionStrategy` class to read a PDF. With this code I can read documents portions based on coords without problems.

Now I get a PDF that seems like the others but if I try to read it I get text like this:

```
2  D   80 D   8 1 M 13M2 R   V / 8  3B 3 3 710 022/F//0 R8 8        1 0 / 3
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
private static string ReadFilePart(string fileName,int pageNumber, int fromLeft, int fromBottom, int width, int height)
{
        var rect = new System.util.RectangleJ(fromLeft, fromBottom, width, height);
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

        var filters = new RenderFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);

        var strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filters);
        var pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pageNumber, new LimitedTextStrategy(strategy));

        pdfReader.Close();

        return pageText;
}

private class LimitedTextStrategy : ITextExtractionStrategy
{

        public readonly ITextExtractionStrategy textextractionstrategy;

        public LimitedTextStrategy(ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
        {
            textextractionstrategy = strategy;
        }

        public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            foreach (TextRenderInfo info in renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
            {
                textextractionstrategy.RenderText(info);
            }
        }
        public string GetResultantText()
        {
            return textextractionstrategy.GetResultantText();
        }

        public void BeginTextBlock()
        {
            textextractionstrategy.BeginTextBlock();

        }
        public void EndTextBlock()
        {
            textextractionstrategy.EndTextBlock();

        }
        public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            textextractionstrategy.RenderImage(renderInfo);
        }
 }
```

I cannot share the PDF file due to sensitive data.

**Update**

If I change `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` with `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` it recognize the full row without strange characters (PDF structure?).

**Update 2**

I can now share the file! Problematic pages are 2° and 3°

[PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y53kkzuq68e526f/test.pdf?dl=0)

[Test solution to read the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxlfopo9prozlye/TestReadPDF.zip?dl=0)

**Update 3**

[mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) pointed me in the right direction and I fixed adding `FistChar`, `LastChar` and `Widths` to all fonts with missing properties with default values.

```
private static PdfReader FontFix(PdfReader pdfReader)
{
        for (var p = 1; p <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; p++)
        {
            var dic = pdfReader.GetPageN(p);
            var resources = dic.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

            var fonts = resources?.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);
            if (fonts == null) continue;

            foreach (var key in fonts.Keys)
            {
                var font = fonts.GetAsDict(key);

                var firstChar = font.Get(PdfName.FIRSTCHAR);
                if(firstChar==null)
                    font.Put(PdfName.FIRSTCHAR, new PdfNumber(0));

                var lastChar = font.Get(PdfName.LASTCHAR);
                if (lastChar == null)
                    font.Put(PdfName.LASTCHAR, new PdfNumber(255));

                var widths= font.GetAsArray(PdfName.WIDTHS);

                if (widths == null)
                {
                    var array=new int[256];
                    array=Enumerable.Repeat(600, 256).ToArray();
                    font.Put(PdfName.WIDTHS, new PdfArray(array));
                }
            }
        }
        return pdfReader;
  }
```

Comment: If you cannot share the pdf, and your strategy works just fine for all other pdfs but not just for this pdf, then it is going to be nigh impossible to help you out I'm afraid. If you are an iText customer with a support contract then we could sign a Non Disclosure Agreement if you like, however we already treat our customers' files as confidential by default.

Comment: If I try to import PDF in Illustrator and save it with default options it works. I think the problem is related to how the file has been created.

Comment: I added a "corrupted" file and a solution with the code I'm using to read PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The error in the PDF

The cause of this issue is that the PDF contains one incomplete font dictionary. Most font dictionaries in the PDF are complete but there is one exception, the dictionary in object 28 used for the font **Fo0** in the shared resources which is used to "fill in" the fields on pages two and three:

```
<<
/Name       /Fo0
/Subtype    /TrueType
/BaseFont   /CourierNew
/Type       /Font
/Encoding   /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
```

In particular this font dictionary does not contain the required **Widths** entry whose value would be an array of the widths of the font glyphs.

Thus, iTextSharp has no idea how wide the glyphs actually are and uses 0 as default value.

*As an aside, such incomplete font dictionaries are allowed (albeit deprecated) for a very limited set of Type 1 fonts, the so called* standard 14 fonts. *The TrueType font "CourierNew" obviously is not among them. But the developer who created the software responsible for the incomplete structure above, probably did not care to look into the PDF specification and simply followed the example of those special Type 1 fonts.*

## The effect on your code

In your `LimitedTextStrategy.RenderText` implementation

```
public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    foreach (TextRenderInfo info in renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
    {
        textextractionstrategy.RenderText(info);
    }
}
```

you split the `renderInfo` (describing a longer string) into multiple `TextRenderInfo` instances (describing one glyph each). If the font of `renderInfo` is the critical **Fo0**, all those `TextRenderInfo` instances have the same position because iTextSharp assumed the glyph widths to be 0.

#### ...using the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`

Those `TextRenderInfo` instances then are filtered and forwarded to the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` which later on sorts them by position. As the positions coincide and the sorting algorithm used does not keep elements with the same position in their original order, this *sorting* effectively shuffles them. Eventually you get all the corresponding characters in a chaotic order.

#### ...using the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`

In this case those `TextRenderInfo` instances then are filtered and forwarded to the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` which does **not** sort them but instead adds the respectively corresponding characters to the result string. If in the content stream the text showing operations occur in reading order, the result returned by the strategies is in proper reading order, too.

## Why does Adobe Reader display the text in proper order?

If confronted with a broken PDF, different programs can attempt different strategies to cope with the situation.

Adobe Reader in the case at hand most likely searches a CourierNew TrueType font program in the operation system and uses the width information from there. This most likely is what the creator of that broken font structure hoped for.

Comment: Do you think can I check page font dictionary with iText and replace font definition with a default one if it is incomplete?

Comment: Yes, you can. Simply retrieve the **Fo0** font resource (which even is shared by all pages of your file) and add the missing entries, in particular **FirstChar**, **LastChar**, and **Widths**.

Comment: Can I find somewhere an example or documentation to achieve this?

Comment: I'll try and write something up. Might take a day or two, though.

Comment: I'm looking here: https://github.com/mapo80/iTextSharp-Monotouch/blob/master/iTextSharp-Monotouch/iTextSharp/text/pdf/Type3Font.cs but it's not so simple to understand logic to extract FirsChar and LastChar. 
I'm doing some attempts...

Comment: I updated with a solution. I don't know if params 0, 255 and fixed 600 are the best choice but for my test it works.

Comment: 600 makes sense, I just created a document with CourierNew and exported it to PDF, and in that export the widths were all 600. Considering the **WinAnsiEncoding** there should be no need for a **FirstChar** less than 32. It most likely doesn't hurt either, though.